# Django, Tests and multidatabases

Tags: python, django, testing, multi-database

I have started to write tests to my django project. However I have question how to solve one problem. As my project has many databases and in my functions I have lines like

```
dbs = DataBaseSettings.objects.using("companies_db").all()
```

thanks to that I am retrieving data from chosen database. As we know, while testing django is creating new databases with prefix test_. So in this case do I have to refactor my whole code and get rid of such lines? Or maybe while testing django automatically creates route from "companies_db" to "test_companies_db"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple tests I found out that the test_companies_db is alias of companies_db. So everything works good.